# htaccess rewriterule for all css file in one condition

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have to make a redirection for all the css files in my project. But there is no common architecture. It can be 
    /css/file.css 
OR 
    /folder/folder/file.css 
etc etc.

Is there any simple rule to redirect all the css files without specify the path everytime?

Comment: `/css/file.css` and `/folder/folder/file.css` are 2 separate files right?

Comment: yes, there are many css files everywhere

Comment: Then how can one rewrite rule redirect them all?

Comment: Where do you want to redirect them **to**?

Comment: i just want to add a rule to read css files. because css files are renammed in name.1267458413.css. It's the timestamp to force the reload of the file.